# What is purpose of using void here in typescript?

Tags: typescript, void, arrow-functions

I cannot understand the purpose of void in the following source code from https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary/blob/master/src/index.tsx. Can anyone explain it?

```
function useErrorHandler(givenError?: unknown): (error: unknown) => void {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState<unknown>(null)
  if (givenError != null) throw givenError
  if (error != null) throw error
  return setError
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break it down a bit, what comes after the colon is the return value of the function:

```
function useErrorHandler(givenError?: unknown): (error: unknown) => void {
//                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So another way of looking at is:

```
type SetError = (error: unknown) => void;
function useErrorHandler(givenError?: unknown): SetError {
```

where `SetError` is the `setError` returned at the end.

`setError`, a state setter function, takes an optional argument, and when the state setter is called, nothing is returned - it doesn't have any return value (even using the return value of `undefined` doesn't make sense), so it's typed as `void`.